# Selecting penultimate record from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

[image]

I need to select penultimate record matching some `probID` and `studentID`. How should I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
    WHERE (probID = 2) AND (studentID = 2)
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

PS: This will not return any result for (probID, studentID) = (2,13), because no penultimate record exists for this combination. If this is not desired, you will need to specify what should happen in this case.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1`? You want to skip 1 row and then read one row in order to get the second.

Comment: What if I don't want the records' order to change in database?

Comment: @user5718409 I may not completely understand your question. The record order (and the database itself) is not changed because this is a `SELECT` statement. The result always returns one row and does not have an order.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_fluxocaixa ORDER BY id_item_fluxo desc limit 1 OFFSET 1;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column_for_find desc LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
```

For me it worked how to above !
because **OFFSET 1** jump first line

and **LIMIT 1** to limit just one line